# How to find out where a function is being called from in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working on an MS Access database application that was created by someone else.  There is one particular line of code (a Function) that will randomly get called and I have no idea why it is being called or what it does.  I have searched (ctrl+F) the entire project for something that calls this function but I can't find it.  How can I find out why this Function is being called? (See below).  Thank you!

```
Public Function Concat(strIOSC As String, strFeature As String) As String

 Static strLastIOSC As String
 Static strFeatures As String

 If strIOSC = strLastIOSC Then
    strFeatures = strFeatures & ", " & strFeature
 Else
     strLastIOSC = strIOSC
     strFeatures = strFeature
 End If

 Concat = strFeatures
```

End Function

Answer (score 2):

If you have only searched the scripts and modules, then your scope is too narrow.

**A public function like this can also be used in expressions, so you need to check queries, reports, form controls, macros, and possibly even tables if you use calculated fields.** Depending on the size of the database, and how often the function is called, you can either search manually in a targeted way or possibly use a public sub to output something searchable. [This sub can get you started. I think it outputs every possible location for expressions.](http://www.datastrat.com/Code/DocDatabase.txt) Unfortunately, each object will have its own text file which will need to be searched separately unless you build a sub to do that too.

As for what your function does, it looks like it logs each input using the `Static strLastIOSC` variable, compares to the arguments passed on the second function call, and if they match it concatenates the two `strFeature` inputs together and outputs the result.

So basically the first argument tells the function whether this is the beginning of a new concatenation instance, or the continuation of an existing instance. The second argument is the item to be concatenated.

The `Static` keyword means that the value is stored even after the function runs so it can compare the last call with the current call to determine whether to add the second argument to the one saved from before, or clear the memory and prepare for a new concatenation.

Given its design, it's probably being used in a query/report/form, where `strIOSC` is likely a primary key field or a field in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: And such a function can also be used in SQL queries, and even as a source in a report (or form) text box control

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful.  I found that is was being called from a query, I wasn't aware that this was possible.